# is possible to use *_lang.php files in javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and i would like to know if is possible to use language files (i.e. user_lang.php) in javascript files (i.e. user.js), and if it is possible, how can I do it?.

Comment: you can just define a lot of global or object-contained strings in a js file, then replace hard-coded string literals in your code with paths to the right string.

Comment: `<script src="whatever.php"></script>` would work, as long as the PHP script outputs pure JS without introducing syntax errors (e.g. php warnings/error messages getting embedded in the output).

Comment: yes, it can works, but don't. I think that I did a wrong question, because I need to load an especific language lang file(i.e. user_lang.php) in an especific javascript file (i.e. user.js) and use all the variables that I declared (i.e, `$lang['error_msg'] = "Complete all fields"`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is a big YES. Like Marc B suggests

```
<script src="whatever.php"></script>
```

**whatever.php**

```
console.log(<?php echo $someVariable ?>);
//more js/jquery code...
```

FYI, you can do the same thing for CSS files as well :)

Comment: yes, it can works, but don't. I think that I did a wrong question, because I need to load an especific language lang file(i.e. user_lang.php) in an especific javascript file (i.e. user.js) and use all the variables that I declared (i.e, `$lang['error_msg'] = "Complete all fields"`)

Comment: @smoreno91 In `whatever.php` you can include your `user_lang.php` file.